# Episode(s) of The Simpsons without all 5 Simpsons?

Tags: the-simpsons

Has there ever been an episode of The Simpsons that didn't include **all** five of the core Simpsons (Marge, Homer, Bart, Lisa and Maggie)?

I like to think of myself as a quite a bit of a Simpsons nut, but when my wife sprung this question on me, I sat and racked my brain for hours, trying to think of the answer. I even went through the plot synopsis for the first 17 seasons, trying to think.

The closest I could come up with, was a Halloween special, or that Maggie or Lisa weren't in it due to the episode being a Bart / Homer heavy one (and the Spinoff Showcase doesn't count, as Lisa was in the previous skits with Chief Wiggum etc.)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

[According to the Simpsons wikia](http://simpsons.wikia.com/wiki/Four_Great_Women_and_a_Manicure):

> "Four Great Women and a Manicure" is the twentieth episode of Season 20, which aired on May 10, 2009. Valentina Garza wrote the episode, while Raymond S. Persi directed. Jodie Foster guest starred as the voice of Maggie. **It should also be noted that this is the only episode where Bart is not seen, nor mentioned. He was only seen in the couch gag**.

The same wiki states that Homer has had lines in **every** episode and Lisa and Marge appeared in every episode though with some line-less ones. Maggie of course, has been missing completely in multiple episodes:

- Bart to the Future
- Stealing First Base
- The Mook, the Chef, the Wife and Her Homer
- Eternal Moonshine of the Simpson Mind
- Team Homer
- American History X-cellent
- Bart Stops to Smell the Roosevelts
- Lisa's Date with Density
- Fraudcast News
- A Midsummer's Nice Dream